# Calculating angle between two vectors

Tags: c#, math, vector, angle

I want to calculate the angle between two System.Numerics.Vector3 but I can't find any function for this. Google only finds results for 2d points. 
I want to implement this in c#.

Comment: How *does* the angle work in 3D space to begin with? On a 2D plane, it is anywhere from 0° to 360°. But what would be the min/max for a 3D space? Or would you get 3 angles, one for each possible pair of the 3 coordinates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var v = new Vector3(1, 2, 3);
var u = new Vector3(4, 5, 6);
var angleInRadians = Math.Acos(Vector3.Dot(v, u) / (v.Length() * u.Length()));
```

Keep in mind that ACos returns radians, so you might need to convert it to degrees. The resulting value should  be between 0 and 180 degrees. You should also ensure that the vectors have a non zero length.

Source:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974178/how-to-calculate-the-angle-between-2-vectors-in-3d-space-given-a-preset-function

Comment: this should be the same like this am I right?  Math.Acos(Vector3.Dot(Vector3.Normalize(pFirstVec), Vector3.Normalize(pSecondVec)));

Comment: @Vectorboy Yes, you can do normalization before or after the dot product.